# How can i change two different things from if statement?

Tags: reactjs

I want to put two different things into my chart with choosing select option from csv file data.
so i tried make 2 functions to do that but for some reason just only one function run.
What i want to do is that `xAxis` and `yAxis` can be changed at the same time.

```js
const DataSetting = ({
...
}) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  const [state2, setState2] = useState();
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);

  const changeState = e => {
    setState2(e.currentTarget.id);
  };
  const clickCheck = e => {
    setState(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  let yAxis;
  let xAxis;
  function axises() {
    if (state === "y") {
      return (yAxis = info.map(i => i[state2]).slice(1, undefined));
    }
  }
  function axises2() {
    if (state === "x") {
      return (xAxis = info.map(i => i[state2]).slice(1, undefined));
    }
  }

  axises();
  axises2();

  let chartData = {
    labels: xAxis,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: title,
        data: yAxis,
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
          "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
          "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
          "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
          "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
          "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
```

```js
const DataMenu = ({
  info,
  setInfo,
  title,
  setTitle,
  clickCheck,
  changeState,
}) => {
  const handleOnDrop = droppedItems => {
    const infos = droppedItems.map(item => item.data);

    setInfo([...infos]);
  };
```

```js
const DataTable = ({ info, clickCheck, changeState }) => {
  return (
    <Paper style={{ border: "3px solid #cfcdcdf8" }}>
      <TableContainer style={{ height: "65.2vh" }}>
        <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
          <TableBody>
            <Choose>
              <MainRow>
                {info.slice(0, 1).map(inf => (
                  <RowFirst>
                    {inf.map((d, index) => (
                      <div className="title">
                        <h5>{d}</h5>
                        <div className="select">
                          <select
                            name=""
                            id={index}
                            onClick={changeState}
                            onChange={clickCheck}
                          >
                            <option value="x">x-axis</option>
                            <option value="y">y-axis</option>
                            <option value="" selected="selected">
                              none
                            </option>
                          </select>{" "}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    ))}
```

and the chart should look like this:
[image]

and this is the result from my code :

[image]

my code is only one thing can change

and this is what select option look like !
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include both the 'if' statements in a single function and call the function wherever.

```
function axises() {
if (state === "y") {
  return (yAxis = info.map(i => i[state2]).slice(1, undefined));
}
if (state === "x") {
      return (xAxis = info.map(i => i[state2]).slice(1, undefined));
    }
  }

 axises();
```

Comment: I did the same thing but result is as same as i did.  Thanks  sir !

Comment: When returning it wont continue in the function. You will need to return an object and handle what to do after, or change it so it isn't a return.

Comment: Is there any references for me to read about that??